# What are the duties of 6 sagun swarup of Narayan and 4 Nirgun Swarup

Tags: puranas

I have heard or read long time back that there are 6 sagun swarup and 4 nirgun swarup of Narayan. in the universe.

Aniruddha, Pradyumna, Sankarshana, Brahama, Vishanu, Mahesh.

And 4 Nirgun swarup:

NarNarayan, LakhamiNarayan, I don't remember other 2 names.

I would like to know what are the duties of Sankarshana, Pradyumna, Aniruddha. and Also the name of other 2 Nirgun swarup.

Thanks

Comment: All followers of Pancharatra Agamas believe that Vishnu has four Vyuha forms: Vasudeva, Sankarshana, Pradyumna, and Aniruddha. But the notion of 6 Sagun Swaroop and 4 Nirgun Swaroop may be unique to the Swaminarayan sect.

Comment: do you know what are the duties of Sankarshana, Pradyumna, and Aniruddha.